# Inequality about squareroots

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

If $a,b\geq 0$ show that $\left| \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right|\leq\sqrt{\left|a-b\right|}$.

WLOG we can assume that $a\geq b$. If one of them is $0$ this is trivial. So assume none of them is $0$. Now,
$$\left| \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\right|\leq\sqrt{\left|a-b\right|} \iff a-2\sqrt{ab}+b\leq a-b \iff -2\sqrt{ab}\leq -2b \iff \sqrt{ab}\geq b \iff ab\geq b^2\iff a\geq b$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It seemed correct to me!

Comment: More ways http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035430/inequality-vert-sqrta-sqrtb-vert-leq-sqrt-vert-a-b-vert